# Render modal partial view via ajax in specified div block

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, partial-views

Is there any possible way to render partial modal view in specified div block? In my variant, modal just does not appeared on view and I don't any ideas how to solve it. Here my variant:

```
<div id="renderModal"></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function onClickEvent(data){
    console.log(data);
    var url = "@Url.Action("Load", "Home")" + '/' + data;

    var renderModal = $('#renderModal');
    $.ajax({
        url: renderModal.data(url),
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        success: function (result) {
            $('#renderModal').html(result);
        }
    });
}
```

Method where I retrieve partial view

```
public virtual async Task<ActionResult> Load(int id)
{
      .  .  .  .

    return PartialView("Partial/_Load", model);
}
```

And Partial view

```
<div id="loadModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" style="text-align: center;">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" style="text-align: center;">
        <div class="modal-content" style="text-align: center">
        <h1>test</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not passing the correct URL, You are not storing any arbitrary data with element, so `renderModal.data(url)` will not return a valid URL.

```
    $.ajax({
        url: url, //renderModal.data(url),          
    });
```

You can also use [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) directly like

```
function onClickEvent(data){
    $('#renderModal').load("@Url.Action("Load", "Home")" + '/' + data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for correction, but still modal does not appeared on view

Comment: @Vitaliy, You can debug the application, Set a break point on controller and check whether it is being hit

Comment: Seems like, it join Load method in the controller and it returns model, but partial view doesn't appeared at the view.